# IMetadataExchange WCF Configuration Error

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

I am getting the below error message in my WCF service. Below is my web,config. I have tried a few things and nothing has resolved the error. Any help is appreciated.

> The contract 'IMetadataExchange' in client configuration does not
>   match the name in the service contract

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
 <connectionStrings/>
   <system.web>
     <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" debug="true"/>
   </system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SNCBinding" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" textEncoding="utf-8">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="SNC.MaterialRequest.WCF.MaterialRequest">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SNCBinding"
      contract="SNC.MaterialRequest.WCF.MaterialRequest" />
  </service>
</services>
 </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your title to be more descriptive. There must be 10,000 questions on this site that are about "WCF Configuration Error".

Comment: When the error seems to be in the **client configuration** - why are you showing us the server-side web.config?? We need to see the **client config file!**

Comment: What client config file? I am using the wcftestclient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you installed the .Net Services SDK by any chance?

See: http://azure.snagy.name/blog/?tag=imetadataexchange

It sounds like it adds a client endpoint for `IMetaDataExchange` in your machine.config. So you can either delete it out of your machine.config, or add

```
<client>
  <remove contract=”IMetadataExchange” name=”sb” />
</client>
```

to every app.config/web.config from now on.

**EDIT:** Note that this shouldn't affect your actual application, it's just a warning that you can ignore. It's mentioned here, also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wcftoolsteamblog/archive/2008/08/28/tips-for-wcf-tools-in-vs2008-sp1.aspx

Comment: No i have not installed teh sdk, This just started happening today, I tried to remove that but I get the same error

Comment: you are correct even though it displays as an error it is just a warning. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue :

```
contract="SNC.MaterialRequest.WCF.MaterialRequest"
```

It's not same as IMetadataExchange in error. So it's either wrong in server side config, or in client side config. Altough I would say in server side, since this should be interface.

Comment: correct, I am not sure where IMetadataExchange is even coming from. I am using basichttpbinding